# How to force a log4net logger to use the root level setting after deleting the logger level

Tags: logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

At system startup, our log4net.config file only has a root logger level:

```
<root>
  <level value="INFO" />      
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="SQLEditionAppender" />
</root>
```

At run-time I'm controlling the specific loggers by adding:

```
<logger name="SomeLoggerName">
  <level value="DEBUG" />
</logger>
```

What I've found is if I delete the logger section entry from the .config file, the logger "SomeLoggerName" won't fall back and start using the root logger setting.  Is there any way to force the logger to start using root again without having to touch the logger "SomeLoggerName" or restarting?

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary - loggers are hierarchical, so unless otherwise directed they will always inherit the root logger settings. The only thing I can think of is that you say _if I delete the logger section entry_, is that while your app is running?

Comment: Yes, while the app is running.

Comment: If you want to reload the configuration while the app is running you need to 'watch' the config file. How are you loading the configuration?

Comment: We are watching for config file changes and it works.  After I add the specific logger control to control specific loggers independently, if I delete that SomeLoggerName entry, the logger will output the last setting set in SomeLoggerName rather than fall back to the setting set in root.

Comment: This may be because log4net caches the loggers - or at least I think it does, but I can't find any documentation on it.